# How to extend specific file of a third-party bundle in Symfony application?

Tags: php, symfony, overriding, bundle, ezpublish

So I have this website that uses ezPublish (which itself is based on Symfony 2.8).

To make it simple, I have this one file `BinaryContent.php` which contains the class `BinaryContent` located at :

`/vendor/ezsystems/ezpublish-kernel/eZ/Publish/Core/REST/Server/Controller`
where `/` is the root of the project (which contains `app/`, `src/`, `web/` folders and so on).

I intend to alter `BinaryContent.php` to implement my own specific logic in a given method. I choose, in that way, to override this file by extending the bundle.

Therefore:

- I tried to extend the bundle as per the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/bundles/inheritance.html#overriding-controllers) but it cleary states that:

  > Overriding controllers in this way **only works if the bundle refers to the controller using the standard FOSUserBundle:Registration:register syntax in routes and templates**. This is the best practice.

I already know it doesn't.

- I have located in `services.yml` of this bundle that this class is registered as a service:

```
    ezpublish_rest.controller.binary_content:
        class: "%ezpublish_rest.controller.binary_content.class%"
        parent: ezpublish_rest.controller.base
        arguments:
            - "@ezpublish.fieldType.ezimage.variation_service"
```

along with

```
parameters:
    ezpublish_rest.controller.binary_content.class: eZ\Publish\Core\REST\Server\Controller\BinaryContent
```

I therefore tried to register the same service with my own class to no avail. When visiting the application, my own `BinaryContent.php` file is not executed (I intentionnaly left a parse error to make it clear).

What should I do?

---

As per [iainn's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47557506/how-to-extend-specific-file-of-a-third-party-bundle-in-symfony-application?noredirect=1#comment82072772_47557506), here is how I try to override the service.

In my `services.yml` file:

```
    ezpublish_rest.controller.binary_content:
        class: Smile\CoreBundle\Core\REST\Server\Controller\BinaryContent
        parent: ezpublish_rest.controller.base
        arguments:
            - "@ezpublish.fieldType.ezimage.variation_service"
```

My custom application bundle is called **after** the `EzPublishCoreBundle` in `AppKernel.php`.

Here's the definition of the `BinaryContent` class:

```
<?php
namespace Smile\CoreBundle\Core\REST\Server\Controller;

use eZ\Publish\Core\REST\Server\Controller\BinaryContent as BaseController;

class BinaryContent extends BaseController {}
```

Comment: Can you show how you tried to override the service, please? It should be possible to override a service purely using the name, assuming the files are loaded in the correct order (i.e. your version is loaded after the original). There are also some more guidelines in the Symfony docs [here](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/bundles/override.html), if you hadn't found them already.

Comment: All you should have to do is to adjust the ezpublish_rest.controller.binary_content.class parameter to point to your own class.  A more sophisticated approach would be to use a compiler pass to modify the service definition.  Avoid bundle extension.  It has never worked well and is going away in S4.

Comment: @Cerad > I have indeed tried to override the `ezpublish_rest.controller.binary_content.class` parameter with the path of my class in my own `parameters.yml` file to no avail. No parse error is raised. My bundle is called after the third-party one I try to override in `AppKernel.php` though.

Comment: @iainn > I edited the question as per your recommendation.

Comment: @D4V1D does my answer helps you? I think it's the possible way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Create a compiler pass which modifies the class of the service definition.

```
final class ReplaceBundleServicePass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $serviceDefinition = $container->getDefinition('bundle_service');

        $serviceDefinition->setClass(MyOwnClass::class);
    }
}
```

Adding compiler passes and when it runs can be found in the official documentation:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#components-di-compiler-pass